# Blender manipulating faces like in Maya

Tags: faces

I cannot manipulate a face like in Maya you can move it accordingly. Even when I try to use the edges as a workaround same issue. Is there another way to achieve manipulating each faces? Someone please help. Using 2.8 btw

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more information? It is hard to tell what you are expecting Blender face manipulating from your question.

Comment: For those of us who don't speak mayan, it is unclear what you are asking. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how it is you want to manipulate those faces. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand .  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: At the top-left of the viewport you can choose vert/edge/face as the selection mode. Activate the face option and you can select faces.

Comment: I am not at my computer right now using my phone or I could have a picture ready but I will try to get something when I get back but let me make it in a way so you understand. You have a face selected and trying to scale it in like you trying to inset but not necessarily inseting just scaling. When I try to scale a selected face it is scaling the whole model instead